# Joomla editor plugin development

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I'm trying to make a plugin for each administration page with editor fields i.e. on the new article page or the new category page.

I'm not sure how exactly I should arrange this. It is a must that the triggers already exist i.e. I don't want to edit any template files.

So I have to use one of these then:

- system type
- content type
- editors type
- editors-xtd type

Where should I put this plugin? A system plugin might work but then the plugin gets triggered on each page which I find not the best

The content type won't get triggered at all.

The Editors type doesn't work either.

The editors-xtd works but it wants a button back as a return vale and I dont have a button because the plugin is mostly javascript based and automatic

What else can I use?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Even though you're talking about a plugin, if you're talking about the editor field Joomla has it built in using JForm:

XML

```
<field name="test1" 
  label ="Test Field" 
  type="editor" 
  width="300" 
  filter="safehtml" 
/>
```

(Note: editor, not editors)  See [this link](http://docs.joomla.org/Standard_form_field_types) for more information.  Also, looks like [this page](http://docs.joomla.org/Component_Development) was just put up yesterday - probably also has more information that could be useful since it sounds like a component may be more useful to you than a plugin.

Comment: Thanks Gisto, but my problem is that a component has its own pages, but I want to manipulate existing pages, thats why I was thinking of a component. AS it seems I can do it via a system plugin since they get called on each page.